# i am trying to pass id to a inner componnet based on the button cliked inside a map fuction

Tags: reactjs

`<ClientProfile />` is a pop up componet i am trying to pass {user.id}  to it

this is my `openClinetProfile` funtion which opens my popup

```
function openClinetProfile() {
    setClient(!client);
  }
```

this is the jsx i just want the syntax of how it is done

```
{client ? <ClientProfile /> : null}



<table>
    <tbody>
                {filteredList(users, search).map((user) => (
                  
                  <tr style={styles.tr}>
                    <button onClick= {openClinetProfile}>
                    //  {user.id}
                      {user.firstname}
                    </button>
                </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

ClientProfile  is a pop up componet i am trying to pass  {user.id}  to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you need to do:

```
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  const openClinetProfile = (id) => {
    setUserId(id);
    setClient(!client);
  }


  //other parts of your code
  //...
  //
  {client ? <ClientProfile userId={userId} /> : null}
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {filteredList(users, search).map((user) => (   
            <tr style={styles.tr}>
              <button onClick= {() => openClinetProfile(user.id)}>
                {user.firstname}
              </button>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: after passing how can i read id in clientprofile componet

Comment: just use react `props` inside your `ClientProfile` component like: `props.userId`